# Unix tools in GUI for Windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, unix, command-line

I am a Windows user and would really like to have the power of the Unix command-line for things to speed up programming. (clean up datafiles, search for occurrences of things in files, file/folder operations/ etc.)

Now I know that using [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and a few ports, I could use these command-line tools in Windows as well.

However, the idea of diving into cryptic command-lines seems hardly tempting.

Is there a GUI which has all the UNIX command-line tools, and which allows for simple drag/drop, connect the lines, set some properties, preview, and save the scripts?

Comment: Actually you got me thinking into creating such a thing for PowerShell. I like graphs and it might work. Though not for everyday tasks but more as a building toolkit for people who don't spend much time on the commandline.

Comment: sounds great! I really see the potential. A lot of users don't have the time to learn 345 switches and commands. But dragging and dropping building blocks (ls, grep, zip, etc but then with more sensible names) and connecting them together, then anyone would soon be able to create powerful scripts

Comment: Well, the problem is that you're hiding complexity and thus power. And a lot of options change semantics; this may mean that a graphical tool would only be able to tap into a very small portion of things you can do.

Comment: why? the commandline switches could still be there but like properties you can set of the boxes. Instead of -R you'd just have a nice graphics toggle called 'Recursive'

Comment: hmmm a quicksilver-like tool to create powershell pipe...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you will get around doing it the old fashioned way. To my knowledge there's no GUI for this. But keep in mind that the command line is also a paradigm for the Unix tools and they would not transfer to a GUI very well.

Comment: why not? If you picture every tool as a box, which can be connected to other boxes (pipes). And the properties of boxes (commandline switches), I can see this working very well.

Comment: @Toad; This sounds an awful lot like how KNIME works (http://www.knime.org/). And it is a very powerful way for non-programmers to build very sophisticated processing and analysis workflows without writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this software

Connection Manager

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use a Unix-like OS with a GUI — you would quickly realise that the GUI is **not** as polished as the Windows GUI.

And to use the command-line tools in such as system you would open an 'xterm' or 'Konsole' which looked pretty much like Cygwin anyway.

So you have to decide do you want to try command-line stuff (with Cygwin) or not.

The command-line needs be only as cryptic as you want, and *there is a learning curve* which you can't avoid, but you can attack at your own pace.

Comment: I think you missed the point. A only need a tool (with a gui) which encapsulates the various (most used) unix tools in such a way that you don't need the commandline tools

Comment: Maybe ... I just don't see how you could best use unix tools *without* the command-line interface. Do you mean a graphical representation of boxes (a la your comment to tliff) where you join them together, much as you do command-line tools, with pipes? This *might* be possible, but unix tools are designed for a different paradigm, emphasising *simplicity* and the command-line is (after a bit of practice) *simple*.

Comment: I think a gui is much simpler. No need to remember all the cryptic options

Comment: I suppose it's all relative. I have trouble when I have deal with a GUI and a help file, for example, says click on 'qaz', then click on 'wsx', then click on 'edc', and the instructions disappear after the first click.

Comment: if the names on the buttons are qaz and wsx, yes than we gain nothing ;^)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how far this will go. Windows is inherently GUI based and the command line is (atleast culturally) seen as a step backwards.

However, there are attempts in the UNIX world to bring command line power to the desktop. I'm not sure how much it helps you but it might start some productive trains of thought. The relevant link is [here](http://live.gnome.org/UnixPowerForDesktop). As far as I can tell, most of them rely on extending the file browser (explorer on windows) with plugins and simple scripts to automate tasks. Perhaps this is an approach you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Not relevent for Windows, but here's a nice article about using WebKit to create a *nix terminal with more panache: http://acko.net/blog/on-termkit

Comment: Looks nice. Some core ideas remind me of PowerShell again, though :-)